# In-Call Status Bar Changes UITableView's header

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have a UITableView in my app that has a very custom section header. One of the things I do is animate this section header by changing its frame property. This all works fine except when I simulate the in-call status bar. Upon doing so, the origin of this particular section header's frame gets reset. Suffice it to say that the UI looks pretty broken at that point.

Any ideas why the in-call status bar would be mucking with my section header? And only the section header?

Answer (score 0):

Almost for sure your tableView springs and struts are not correct. Make sure the strut is set top and bottom, and the inner spring is on.

Comment: I ended up putting my custom view inside a blank UIView. That way, the parent UIView's transform can get reset without changing my custom section header's transform.